# What would you call a person who farts a lot?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I came across one word that is "gas-bag." Are there any other specific (not slang) words?

Comment: Voting to close as general reference--Googling this finds the "official" word of "flatulent".

Comment: Close it . I am fine with it

Comment: I'm not adding anything here...but I call that person a demolition expert because they're "blowing it up" all the time...

Comment: What about a **fartalot**?

Comment: There was a Frenchman who performed (naked) with his comically egregious emissions. He had names for each variation on the theme, and he drew great crowds of men (no women allowed). His stage name was "Le Petomaine" (not sure of the spelling). I suppose you could Google his stage name and find the name of the book which included the story of Le Petomaine. I have a feeling it was in a Peter Laurence book, if memory serves.

Comment: Flatulent is the best fit - 'gasbag' in the UK just means you talk too much.

Comment: If I were choosing I'd go with [Sir Fartsalot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CU8xQDos4zY).

Comment: @bamboo I've only just realised this, could the use of _gas-bag_ for a garrulous person (which was what I thought of as well) have its origin in the usage quoted by the OP?

Comment: @BoldBen - I don't know for sure, I'd think it unlikely - in the UK, there is no single vernacular word or expression for someone who's flatulent other than flatulent, or someone might say they pass wind/fart a lot - gasbag has a very specific meaning and that's someone who not only talks a lot but most if it won't be informative, as in 'empty vessels make the most noise'; also windbag, but you don't hear either expression much any more

Comment: @bamboo _Flatulent_, being Latin based, doesn't sound like an old working class word to me, it sounds more middle/upper/educated classes. I find it difficult to believe that working class speech and Anglo-Saxon didn't have an expression for something so basic and wonder whether gas-bag was that term. I am British by the way.

Comment: @BoldBen I'm a Brit too - talking about flatulence, whatever you called it, was rarely done, but in my very much working class memory of childhood, people used to say they 'had wind' or 'indigestion' or that someone suffered from 'wind' or was always 'passing wind' - I never heard the word fart till I was an adult, that was considered a borderline swear word even back in the early seventies and even with my London 'council estate' background. Certainly, it was never referred to as 'gas', always 'wind' - but it may have been different for blokes amongst themselves!

Comment: @BoldBen - I just spoke to my sister, and she also recalls our grandfather using the word 'flatulence' or 'flatulent' with great relish - perhaps he'd not long learned the word, I don't know, but you couldn't have got more working class than he was.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Further to Thusagen's answer, the single word would be **flatulent**.

Answer (score 3):

This person, in medicine, would have been called, "someone suffering from **excessive flatulence**"

Answer (score 3):

The French performer [Le Pétomane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_P%C3%A9tomane), was a professional flatulist, who was known by several terms:

- [Flatulist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatulist)
- [Fartiste](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2011/11/16/the-fartiste-musical_n_1082637.html)
- Farteur

From Wikipedia (linked above):

> Le Pétomane (/ləˈpɛtəmeɪn/, French pronunciation: ​[ləpetɔˈman]) was the stage name of the French flatulist (professional farter) and entertainer Joseph Pujol (June 1, 1857 – 1945). He was famous for his remarkable control of the abdominal muscles, which enabled him to seemingly fart at will. His stage name combines the French verb péter, "to fart" with the -mane, "-maniac" suffix, which translates to "fartomaniac". The profession is also referred to as "flatulist", "farteur", or "fartiste".[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_P%C3%A9tomane)

Answer (score 2):

I personally call such a person a fart-machine. ;)

But the correct term is **flatulent**.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call them a *[fart-arse](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fart-arse)*, a term which has expanded to include a number of other meanings:-

> fart-arse (plural fart-arses)
>
> (UK, slang, derogatory) A generic term of insult.
>
> Verb
>
> fart-arse (third-person singular simple present fart-arses, present
>   participle fart-arsing, simple past and past participle fart-arsed)
>
> (UK, slang) To waste time or opportunities; to dawdle.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how spread it is but I've heard the term "*sir farts-a-lot*". Although, the correct and polite way is "*flatulent*".

Answer (score 0):

In *Show Bussiness* is called the **Fart-Maker**.

Answer (score 0):

**Smelly.**  Common nickname for a person who farts a lot.